# Regex for Email validation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, email

I want to check for valid Email address in my iOS application.
I want to check for "abc@abc.com", "abc@abc.co.in". Now i am doing this with two different regex. I wan to check these to condition in one regex.

Comment: Did you google search this?

Comment: Can you add your existing regexes, along with what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/vE6pH2/1)

Simple form: `^[^@]+@([^.]+\.?){1,2}\.\w+$`

the ([^.]+.?) will match subdomain, once or twice, matching your two exemple but NOT abc@sub.abc.co.in

Comment: it confirms RFC5322 [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])+